# When I execute (idea .) in git bash (Intellij Idea opens But) its stops until I close the intellij idea why?

Tags: bash, git, intellij-idea, sh, git-bash

```
USER@DESKTOP-COMPUTER MINGW64 /f/NewFolder/Learning
$ idea .
(Cursor stays here until I close Idea)
```

CMD does not behave like this. After opening Idea CMD returns to its original form where it can accept code.

**THIS ONLY HAPPENS WITH INTELLIJ (IDEA, Pycharm, etc), VSCODE ATOM WORKS FINE IN GIT BASH**

***How Can I overcome this problem with git bash?***

Comment: try `app . &` , you should run it in detach mode

Comment: Thanks Detach Mode Works, But Now if i close the bash window the app also closes

Comment: I don't use intellij-idea, but most IDEs are set up to be launched by the system launcher (the OS X Dock, or the WIndows tray, or whatever) when you want to use them the way you're describing. When you're in bash, you're using a command-based *programming language*, where you invoke a program and wait for its result by default.

Comment: IDEs tend to interact *very badly* with this entire idea. It's a bit like trying to power your electric car by pouring gasoline over the battery. Don't do that! Some (like VSCode and Atom) systems attempt to figure out which way you're using them and auto-adjust, and this sometimes works, but it causes other problems: for instance if you configure atom as your Git editor, you have to tell Git to run it as `atom --wait` rather than just `atom`.

Comment: I tried it on windows cause I have seen idea provide this feature in linux and macOS with the name command line launcher , but I dont get it why not Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `app . &`:

you should run it in detached mode

e.g

```
rider . &
```